# $t^{6}-2t^{3}-1$ irreducible Polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I need to show that

> $t^{6}-2t^{3}-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I tried to express it, in three different ways, such:

$t^{6}-2t^{3}-1= (t^{3}+a)(t^{3}+b)$. In this way, I got a contradiction.

$t^{6}-2t^{3}-1= (t^{4}+at^{3}+bt^{2}+ct +d)(t^{2}+\alpha t + \beta)$. In this way, there are many combinations.

$t^{6}-2t^{3}-1= (t^{5}+at^{4}+bt^{3}+ct^{2} +dt +e)(t+\alpha )$. I think, I will get a contradiction.

There is an easier way to show that it is irreducible ?
Thanks

Pd. I also tried the eisenstein's criterion, but it can't apply for this.

Comment: You can definitely find a contradiction for case 3: simply apply the rational roots theorem to show that there are no rational roots (and therefore it will not reduce into a product of a linear and a quintic).

Comment: Is the second case all that bad?  We can take the coefficients to be integers, then $d=-\beta=\pm1$, then $c=\alpha$, and I haven't taken it any further, but we seem to be getting somewhere without too much work.

Comment: @KajHansen Ok, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My immediate thought is to show that $$\mathbb{Q}[t]/(t^6 - 2t^3 - 1)$$ is a domain.  This is tough to do directly, but if we first look at a field extension $K / \mathbb{Q}$ where $K = \mathbb{Q}[x] / (x^2 - 2x - 1)$ which is absolutely a field (since $x^2 - 2x- 1$ is irreducible). Then what is $t$? It's just a third root of $x$, so $$\mathbb{Q}[t]/(t^6 - 2t^3 -1) = K[t]/(x-t^3)$$
And since $K$ is a field and $x-t^3$ is irreducible, $\mathbb{Q}[t]/(t^6-2t^3 - 1)$ is a field.

Obviously you'll have to check some details.